# I'm starting to learn Java-based config. Postman don't see my query and return error 404

Tags: java, spring, oracle, postman

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5wsp.png)i ran my program without java-based config with web.xml. when i use java-based config my postman don't see any query and return error 404.

I thought this problem is due to beans. placed everywhere anotation.

```
package com.lesson3.hometask.Controller;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.lesson3.hometask.Model.Storage;
import com.lesson3.hometask.Service.Service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

@Controller
@Component
public class StorageController{
    private Service service;

    @Autowired
    public StorageController(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/storageSave")
    public @ResponseBody
    String save(HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException {
        return service.save(readValuesPostman(req), Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("id"))).toString();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/storageFind")
    public @ResponseBody
    String findById(HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException {
        return service.findById(Storage.class, Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("id"))).toString();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "/storageDelete")
    public @ResponseBody
    String delete(HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException {
        service.delete(Storage.class, Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("id")));
        return service.findById(Storage.class, Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("id"))).toString();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/storageUpdate")
    public @ResponseBody
    String update(HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException {
        service.update(readValuesPostman(req));
        return readValuesPostman(req).toString();
    }

    private Storage readValuesPostman(HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException {
        Storage storage;
        try(BufferedReader reader = req.getReader()) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            storage = gson.fromJson(reader, Storage.class);
        }
        return storage;
    }
}
```

```
package com.lesson3.hometask.Model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

@Entity
@Table(name = "STORAGE")
public class Storage {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "STORAGE_SEQ", sequenceName = "STORAGE_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "STORAGE_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "FORMATS_SUPPORTED")
    private String formatsSupported;
    @Column(name = "STORAGE_COUNTRY")
    private String storageCountry;
    @Column(name = "STORAGE_MAX_SIZE")
    private Long storageMaxSize;

    public Storage() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFormatsSupported() {
        return formatsSupported;
    }

    public void setFormatsSupported(String formatsSupported) {
        this.formatsSupported = formatsSupported;
    }

    public String getStorageCountry() {
        return storageCountry;
    }

    public void setStorageCountry(String storageCountry) {
        this.storageCountry = storageCountry;
    }

    public long getStorageMaxSize() {
        return storageMaxSize;
    }

    public void setStorageMaxSize(Long storageMaxSize) {
        this.storageMaxSize = storageMaxSize;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Storage{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", formatsSupported='" + formatsSupported + '\'' +
                ", storageCountry='" + storageCountry + '\'' +
                ", storageMaxSize=" + storageMaxSize +
                '}';
    }
}
```

```
package config;

import com.lesson3.hometask.DAO.DAO;
import com.lesson3.hometask.Service.Service;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;


@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com"})
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppContext implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean(name = "service")
    public Service service(){
        return new Service();
    }

    @Bean(name = "DAO")
    public DAO dao(){
        return new DAO();
    }
}
```

```
package config;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    // Указываем имя нашему Servlet Dispatcher для мапинга
    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        // Регистрируем в контексте конфигурационный класс, который мы создадим ниже
        ctx.register(AppContext.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME, new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }

}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Spring1.3</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring1.3</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>18.3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

postman return error 404 = "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not
        willing to disclose that one exists".

Comment: can you share your postman image, how u r calling?

Comment: have you started your server?

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: @pvpkiran I left a link to the picture

Comment: did you try with url http://localhost:8080/storageSave? And also in the postman ther eis headers tab. I see there is one header, what are you passing there.

Comment: @pvpkiran ye, i try simply localhost:8080/storageSave. In the headers i nothing not writing. may be postman create some kind date.